# How do I add "Edit with Notepad++" to the Windows context menu (without admin access)?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, user-accounts, context-menu

Here's a simple question. Is there an easy way to add "Edit with Notepad++" to the Windows 7 context menu?

I want the option to appear any time I right click a file in Windows Explorer. I don't have administrator access on this laptop, as this is an employee workstation provided by my job.

It's worth noting that I am using the desktop version of Notepad++, [as opposed to the portable version](https://superuser.com/q/1137373/358766).

Comment: Notepad++ is generally accepted as software that is okay to be used in a business environment. Ask your IT people if its okay if they install it for you. They likely will, and it beats any workaround.

Answer (score 8):

**Registry Method**

You can try to create a new key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` in the registry as detailed in [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/). But it is likely you will not have the permissions to do so and will encounter this error:

[image]

**Send To Method**

I found an alternative method in your [linked question](https://superuser.com/a/1137379/206587): add a shortcut to Notepad++ in the SendTo folder. Access the SendTo folder by typing `shell:sendto` in the run dialog. You may then right-click any file and open it in Notepad++ under the Send To menu:

[image]

Comment: Just an additional note that plugins' .dlls should be copied as well or else you'll get a warning when you `send to`

Comment: @FueledByCoffee , I don't have that issue on my PC. Did you create a shortcut within the SendTo folder or did you copy the executable?

Answer (score 5):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` provides a merged view of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` which makes it possible to achieve your goal by editing the latter. For instance, here's a reg-file that would add an entry called 'Hulk Smash' to the right-click context menu of any file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Hulk Smash\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Simply create a new file, paste the above text into it and save it under whatever name you please. Now, you can't use `regedit.exe` to import the file because it requires admin privileges even though not all hives actually need admin permissions to access. To work around that, you can use `reg.exe` like this:

```
reg.exe import <nameofyourfile.ext>
```

The new entry should appear immediately.

If you want to remove the entry from the context menu again, just use the following file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Hulk Smash]
```

Comment: thx for answer, it partially solved my problem: using this method, notepad++ is run in background. I mean, it does not become the active window after opening that file. Can you find any fix about it?