# Right click main context menu. How to create New Text Document just by right clicking on anywhere on windows explorer (Notepad)?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, right-click

Here's the link to the same question here on this site.
[I'm dreaming of Right click > New Text Document (Notepad)](https://superuser.com/questions/1477912/im-dreaming-of-right-click-new-text-document-notepad)

But it seems no one willing to answer this. As this would be very helpful for me, I'm just asking the question again if someone kind enough to answer and make this possible.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Could be it the answer of your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1137373/how-to-add-open-with-notepad-portable-to-windows-context-menu

Comment: NO! This actually doesn't work on what I wanted. I can do add registry that opens any application. I rather wanted to get the "Text Document" out of the "New" sub-menu but works in the same way.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question specifically states that this is the same as a question already asked. We aren't "scared" to answer, no one has found the answer and been to this site. Read the Help section please to learn how this site works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes this is a duplicate of an existing question already and does not produce any new or additional information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["New Word Document" missing from right-click context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/439005/new-word-document-missing-from-right-click-context-menu)

Answer (score 4):

You can try these steps:

- Open registry editor as administrator.
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`.
- Now in the `shell` key, add a key named `New Text Document`.
- Then in the new key, add another key named `command`.
- Then in the `command` key, edit the Default value to `cmd.exe /c notepad.exe "New Text Document.txt" & taskkill /im notepad.exe`.

I have tested it and it is working.

Comment: NO! This doesn't work as expected. Here's the link to a video I've made explaining how I want it to work. 

https://youtu.be/3bsNBirrOeA

Thank you!